# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. Laravel and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to understand how to save data from ajax to laravel database.
But i got this error:
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

I hope you can help me a little bit.

web.php

```
Route::post('postdataCord', 'HomeController@postdataCord')->middleware('auth');
```

Controller

```
    public function postdataCord(Request $request)
    {
        $myId = auth()->id();
        $long = $request->long;
        $lat = $request->lat;

        $data = User::find($request->get($myId));
        $data->long = $long;
        $data->lat = $lat;
        $data->save();   
    }
```

The Script Blade

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
            });

            const successCallback = (position) => {
                var long = position.coords.longitude;
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                console.log(long, lat);

                var datastr = "long=" + long + "&lat=" + lat;
                $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url: "postdataCord",
                            data: datastr,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data){


                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, status, err){

                            }

                        });

            };
            const errorCallback = (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            };

            const watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 60000,
            maximumAge: 0
            });
            
        });
```

Comment: Your ` type: "post",` might be not getting recognised I do not think ` type: "POST",` will make any difference but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

change your route type to post
you need a form like this

```
<form id="id_of_form" onsubmit="ajaxUpdate()" class="form-horizontal col-lg- offset-2" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

try this for ajax request

```
function ajaxUpdate() {
var inputs = $('#id_of_form').serializeArray();

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'your/route/url',
                    data:inputs,
                    success:function(data){
                        if(data.status == 200) {
                            // code what happen if success

                        }
                    }
                });
}
```